How does the Merciful weapon enchancement interact with Sneak Attack?
I am putting some loot piles together, and for the rogue in the group I wanted the character to receive a dagger with the Merciful enhancement (DMG p.225) - so that the rogue could potentially capture enemy patrols and the like, using his high sneak attack damage to knock unsuspecting guards out in one quick attack using lots of nonlethal damage.
I think I found a bit of a rules problem, though. In looking over the specifics of the rogue's Sneak Attack, it looks like a Merciful Dagger might not be able to deal non-lethal Sneak Attack damage.
The Merciful property says of the weapon it enhances "all damage it [the weapon] deals is nonlethal damage," (Ibid.) but the rogue's sneak attack says "[t]he rogue’s attack deals extra damage," (PHB p.50) which suggests it isn't the weapon that deals the damage - and further the sneak attack entry goes on to say:

"With a sap (blackjack) or an unarmed strike, a rogue can make a sneak attack that deals nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage. She cannot use a weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage in a sneak attack, not even with the usual. (Ibid.)

The first sentence just up front tells us that rogues can only deal nonlethal sneak attack damage in a sneak attack with a sap or with unarmed strikes. And the second sentence limits that a rogue cannot take advantage of the Nonlethal Damage with a Weapon that Deals Lethal Damage rule (PHB p.146) and also sneak attack.
Which seems clear enough, though a bit wonky: The rogue can attack using the Merciful dagger, and the damage from the dagger and the merciful property are clearly nonlethal, however any sneak attack bonus damage is - somehow - lethal damage, if I am parsing this correctly?
And that rule is definitely repeated, though broadened for all other precision damage users, in what the Rules Compendium says under Precision Damage, in part, "[a]n attacker can deal precision damage with any weapon he can wield, but he must wield that weapon in the optimal way. If an attacker takes the –4 penalty to deal nonlethal damage with a lethal weapon, for example, no precision damage is possible." (RC p.42)
However, I seem to recall some supplemental rule in Complete Scoundrel (or perhaps Song and Silence) that when a Rogue uses a weapon that deals non-lethal, any applicable sneak attack damage would also be nonlethal - which is more sensible, though I cannot find the rule and am starting to think it's just a crept in houserule.
Is there such a rule, or is it correct that the rogue would bizarrely deal both nonlethal and lethal damage if using the Merciful Dagger? (Or, rather, am I stuck awarding a Merciful Sap instead?)
[This answer is tangentially related, and potentially helpful for answerers.]

The merciful damage can do non-lethal sneak attack damage
First, there's Rule 0 - you're the DM, you interpret the rules.
Beyond that, this is the most straightforward reading of the rules.

With a sap (blackjack) or an unarmed strike, a rogue can make a sneak attack that deals nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage.

OK. Why? Well, it's because those weapons deal non-lethal damage.

She cannot use a weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage in a sneak attack ...

OK. But the merciful dagger is not "a weapon that deals lethal damage", so this part isn't applicable.

"[a]n attacker can deal precision damage with any weapon he can wield, but he must wield that weapon in the optimal way. If an attacker takes the –4 penalty to deal nonlethal damage with a lethal weapon, for example, no precision damage is possible."

OK. But they don't take a -4 penalty to do non-lethal damage, they just do. So, this isn't applicable.

FWIW, the whip and the bolas (both in the PHB) also deal nonlethal damage, but are not listed in the acceptable methods for a rogue to deal nonlethal Sneak Attack damage. If the "why" of the rule was because those weapons already deal nonlethal, it seems that the clause regarding the sap and the unarmed strike would include the bolas and whip, or would simply say "with a weapon that normally deals nonlethal" or some-such similar verbiage.

@NFeutz While speculating about “why” is probably questionable in general, in this case, those almost-certainly are not mentioned because a rogue is not proficient with them. Dale is thus most likely mostly correct here, those two are listed because they are the core rogue weapons that deal nonlethal damage.

I am taking the perspective that we are only interested in precisely what the rules text does or doesn’t say. I consider the question of how these should interact completely obvious—a merciful weapon should deal nonlethal damage with sneak attack, just as a sap or unarmed strike does. Thus, this answer doesn’t concern itself with that question, and addresses solely the Rules As Written.
First of all, we have to make very clear that this sentence:

With a sap (blackjack) or an unarmed strike, a rogue can make a sneak attack that deals nonlethal damage instead of lethal damage.

is completely irrelevant here. You aren’t wielding a sap or unarmed strike, so this sentence doesn’t apply. Note that the logical implication of this sentence,

sap or unarmed strike → nonlethal sneak attack

does not imply the reverse, that is,

not (sap or unarmed strike) ↛ not (nonlethal sneak attack).

This would be denying the antecedent, a logical fallacy. In actual fact, the statement “not (sap or unarmed strike)” implies nothing here, from this statement.
The next sentence is

She cannot use a weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage in a sneak attack, not even with the usual −4 penalty.

This sentence is ambiguous: what does it mean to “use a weapon […] to deal nonlethal damage”? Does a merciful weapon count as “a weapon that deals lethal damage”?
Both questions can be addressed by treating the sneak attack rules and the merciful rules as atomic—that is, you must fully resolve the rules for one before you can consider the rules for the other. This is not necessarily “the” way to read the rules, nothing in the rules says that rule elements are atomic. That said, they’re certainly written as if they’re atomic: nothing about their wording suggests that they can or should be interleaved.
So if they are both atomic, the question becomes, which is resolved first? There are no general rules for that: the FAQ suggests that the controller of the effects decide their order as a rule of thumb, but it’s only ever that. In this case, though, merciful suggests that it is a constant effect on the weapon, it’s not something that the weapon can do, it’s something that the weapon is. Thus, it probably makes the most sense to resolve it first.
If you do, then “all damage [the merciful weapon] deals is nonlethal damage,” which means it is not “a weapon that deals lethal damage.” Since it’s neither a “sap (blackjack) or unarmed strike” nor “a weapon that deals lethal damage,” both rules we have on this subject fail to apply to the merciful weapon. (Even without merciful getting involved, bolas and whips are core weapons with the same problem.)
Thus, we have rules allowing the merciful weapon to be used (since we have rules allowing a rogue to sneak attack without any limitation that would bar merciful), and rules for how to calculate the amount of damage (as usual for sneak attack), but nothing on the subject of lethal or nonlethal. And that’s actually fine! We don’t, strictly speaking, need them: a paladin’s smite or a fighter’s Power Attack don’t specify that, either, and they just work. Sneak attack adds a bonus to your damage roll. Whatever number you rolled for damage is now that much higher. The type of damage doesn’t change, and that includes lethal or not. Since our merciful weapon was dealing nonlethal damage, and sneak attack is just increasing the amount of damage, the sneak attack with a merciful weapon just deals more nonlethal damage.
(If you’re wondering, at this point, what the purpose of those two sentences is, they do matter when dealing with sap and unarmed strikes, or with weapons that are dealing lethal damage: in both cases, the rogue doesn’t get to choose if the sneak attack damage is lethal or not, that’s fixed by the rules, and can’t be changed “even with the usual −4 penalty.”)
On the other hand, if we—despite the wording on merciful—read sneak attack as resolving first, then—at the time we’re resolving sneak attack—our weapon is dealing lethal damage. As such, sneak attack mandates that it continues to deal lethal damage, just a larger amount of it. But then when we resolve merciful after that, it converts all of the damage to nonlethal—and since sneak attack has already been resolved, its mandate that the sneak attack damage be lethal has already been handled and no longer affects things—it was lethal then, it only became nonlethal later.
Either way, the sneak attack with the merciful weapon does the full sneak attack damage, all as nonlethal damage. Which is how it should be, and how it is.

I think the main crux of the rule issue is that Merciful says one thing should happen, but the "[w]ith a sap (blackjack) or unarmed strike [...]" clause says another thing should happen. Specifically, the former is saying the sneak attack damage should be nonlethal, and the latter is saying that the sneak attack damage should be lethal. [With regard to the Merciful Dagger, at any rate.]

@NFeutz why does it really matter? You're the DM. And in the question said you want merciful weapons to deal non-lethal sneak attack damage? If so, why are you arguing against it? Just pick one - if you really are not convinced, then rule it so Merciful weapons still deal lethal sneak damage and you're done.

@VLAZ If we allowed that kind of answer, that would be the #1 go to answer on this site for a large number of the questions. "You're the GM, just make it work," is always on the table as a tool - and certainly I probably would rule that the Merciful weapon should behave in a more sensible fashion... but still, I want the strongest possible answer, regardless of if the answer agrees with what I "want" from the rules. There may be others, in the future, with a similar question, and I think they (and I!) should at least get the benefit of a robust examination of the relevant rules.

@NFeutz but like it doesn't matter in this case. You're want X, you've been given two answers supporting X, you then disputed these answers. Just do not-X if you don't want X. In the end it's almost irrelevant which way you go. This isn't a big issue - if you want rogues to deal non-lethal weapons with a dagger and they do then...nothing worth noting happens other than you and the player having more fun. Before you try to tell me "but what if..." that doesn't apply to all situations. Like, if somebody wants to make enemies explode with one punch, then that's different.

@NFeutz also feel free to put your own answer that points out why you think the two are not correct. If you really want the future generations to go with that interpretation, provide it for them.

@VLAZ I feel that you misunderstand me: I didn't dispute those answers because I disagree with the answers, but because this site is exactly for the purpose of building a collection of strong answers which, when relevant, stand up to potential counterpoints or otherwise clarify thorny rules interactions. This doesn't make the answer any weaker, instead it makes the answer better. In fact, I didn't think I "disputed" the given answers, just offered my own clarification to each as to why I see what I think is a bit of a rules issue, and hope their answers might be edited to address that.

@NFeutz First key insight is that the statement about “a sap (blackjack) or unarmed strike” tells us nothing about other weapons—it’s logically invalid to extrapolate that to meaning other weapons don’t deal nonlethal damage. Then we get the statement about “a weapon that deals lethal damage”—but after merciful applies, our weapon isn’t that, either. So that rule doesn’t apply either. That leaves us with no rule that covers the situation. Alternatively—as in my answer—we treat the attack as lethal for sneak attack, and apply merciful after, converting it to nonlethal then.

@KRyan That's awfully close to "nothing in the rules says a dog can't play basketball" territory, and is not an argument I will accept. The rules for sneak attack make it clear that in the right conditions, sneak attack damage happens. Sneak attack also carves out an exception for nonlethal damage. Outside of that exception, we're back to dealing "normal" sneak attack damage - which is lethal. I don't see "no rule" covering this situation - I see two rules covering this situation which are butting heads. Cheers.

@NFeutz No, it’s not, and whether or not you accept it, your position is one based solely in logical fallacy. Nothing in the rules says that sneak attack “is lethal” “outside of that exception,” that is purely your own insertion not found anywhere in the rules text. You are denying the antecedent, and it’s a mistake. Anyway, edited my answer to get into these issues more deeply.

@KRyan The rules are clear. When a rogue meets the conditions, a sneak attack occurs. The sneak attack does nonlethal damage under Y conditions. The usage case spelled out in the question does not satisfy Y conditions - or it strongly appears that way. I can't find any other text that clarifies this. And denying the antecedent is meaningful for conditional logic, but we aren't playing conditional logic. Nor am I denying an antecedent. It's been a while since I took my old rhetoric class, but if it is not that case that A, then the B that would follow cannot be accepted. (A AND NOT B)

@NFeutz I don’t know what to tell you. You are convinced that saps and unarmed strikes doing nonlethal damage automatically means everything else always must do lethal damage no matter what, and refuse to consider both common sense (this is a rules hole with a really obvious filler) or strict logic (your reasoning is fallacious). It sounds like you are only ready to accept an answer that no one will give you because it’s incorrect. And in your example, B cannot be proven (based on solely that information), but it likewise can’t be rejected, either, which is what you are trying to do.
